# Checking if the Rows of the 2D array is true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D array of boolean[30,10]. those are all set to false. I only want to check if the Rows are filled. so example. if the rows of the 0th column are all true. Then I debug returning say: "First row are all true". Same goes for all other columns. If the 5th column and his rows are also all true. Then I return say: "Fifth row of booleans are all true"

```
private bool[,] grid = new bool[30,10];

for( int y = 0; x < grid.GetLength(0); y++ )
{
  for( int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(1); x++ )
  {
    if ( grid[y,x] == true )
    {
      Debug.Log(y + "th rows are filled!");
    }
  }
}
```

There are just my pseudo codes. they don't work i know. but does someone know how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of, a very small issue, in your first for loop you, you wrote

```
for (int y = 0; **x** < grid.GetLength(0); y++)
```

instead you should write:

```
for (int y = 0; **y** < grid.GetLength(0); y++) ;
```

but unfortunately it's not the problem :(

In your code you are going through every element in a row and checking if it is true, and here is the problem, this if statement:

```
    if(grid[y,x] == true){
       Debug.Log(y + "th rows are filled!");
```

is checking if the first element is true, if it is, it will print out that **the whole**
row is filled with true variables. Instead I offer this solution:

```
bool[,] grid = new bool[2,2];
bool isRowTrue = true;
for (int y = 0; y < grid.GetLength(0); y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(1); x++)
    {
        if (grid[y, x] == false)
        {
            isRowTrue = false;
            break;
        }
    }
  if (isRowTrue == true)
  {
      Debug.Log(y + "th are all true!");
  }
  else {
      isRowTrue = true;
  }
}
```

I hope I've understood your problem correctly, if not, my apologies, tell me and I will try to understand and help.

Answer (score 1):

To loop through check if an array of values is all true do this:

```
private bool[,] grid = new bool[30,10];
for(int y = 0; x < grid.GetLength(0); y++){
 bool row = true;
 for(int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(1); x++)
   row &&= grid[y,x]; // row stays true until it encounters a false
 if (row) Debug.Log(y + " row is filled");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int rows = 30;
int cols = 10;
bool[,] grid = new bool[rows,cols];

InitializeGrid(grid);

for (int row = 0 ; row < rows ; ++row )
{
  bool isAllTrue = true;

  for( int col = 0 ; col < cols ; ++col {

    if ( !grid[row,col] )
    {
      isAllTrue = false;
      break;
    }

  }

  if (isAllTrue)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Row {row} is all true");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/using-foreach-with-arrays)  loop like

```
private bool[,] grid = new bool[30,10];

bool allAreTrue = true;
foreach(var b in grid)
{
    if(!b) 
    {
        allAreTrue = false;

        // No need to check others anymore
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Or you could use [Linq All](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all) after converting the multi dimensional array to an enumerable using [`Linq OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype)

```
using System.Linq;

...

private bool[,] grid = new bool[30,10];

var allAreTrue = grid.OfType<bool>().All(b => !b);
```